# Cronjob schedule

Tags: cron

I have a task which I wanted it to run on every hour 56 minutes not sure which I should do below and what does "*/number" means.

An example :- 12:56PM, 01:56PM, 02:56PM ...

**Use this ?**

```
*/56 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/asd/asd.py
```

**Or**

```
56 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/asd/asd.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using just 56 on the first field you are telling cron you want to run the script at minute 56; while setting "*/56" on the first field you are telling crontab to run the script every 56 minutes.

If You want the script to run at 12:56PM, 01:56PM, 02:56PM ...; then you use 56

```
56 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/asd/asd.py
```