# how does cron react to ranges where using a non-even separator?

Tags: cron

Suppose that we want to run a task every 20 minutes:

```
0/20 * * * *
```

It would run at `X:00`, `X:20`, `X:40` and so on.

Every 15?

```
0/15 * * * *
```

So it would run at `X:00`, `X:15`, `X:30` and `X:45`.

But what happens if we wanted to run every **45** minutes?

```
0/45 * * * *
```

I am inclined to think that it would run at `X:00`, then at `X:45`, then at `X+1:00` (which is not what I need, by the way)? Or it would run at `X+1:30` (exactly what I need)?

[Cronjob schedule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186329/cronjob-schedule) explains that it would *always* separate runs by 45 minutes but the question was related to running at X minutes every hour so their **correct answer** doesn't really apply to my case and I want to be sure of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value after the slash is the step value.  (See the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)).

So 0/45 in the minutes filed means it’ll run at 1:00, 1:45, 2:00, 2:45, 3:00, etc.  it doesn’t mean every 45 minutes.

/15, /20, /30, all work as expected because 60 divides evenly by those values.

If you want to have it run every 45 minutes, you’ll likely have to create multiple lines with the various hours and minutes.